# Knockout + JQuery sortable = list items disappears

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I've been searching the web and scratching my head for hours!

I have a knockout observable array that I can rearrange with a binding to jQuery Sortable. All is working fine except for one annoying little bug.

If I drag the second list item above the first (without dropping) and then back and drop it into it's original place, and then drag the first list item and drop it between the second and third... the second list item disappears!

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: headers, uiSortableList: headers" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uiSortableList = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccesor, context) {
        var list = valueAccessor();

        $(element).sortable({
            axis: 'y',
            update: function (event, ui) {
                var item = ko.dataFor(ui.item[0]);
                var newIndex = ui.item.index();

                if (list.indexOf(item) != newIndex) {
                    ui.item.remove();
                    list.remove(item);
                    list.splice(newIndex, 0, item);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.headers = ko.observableArray([
        {title: 'One'},
        {title: 'Two'},
        {title: 'Three'},
        {title: 'Four'}
    ]);
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

External scripts:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/connyake/w1Lgqtug/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have both the observableArray and jQuery vying for control of the displayed elements. In this case, you want jQuery to control the view, and to reflect its changes into the array, without intermediate changes being reflected *back* into the view.

So instead of doing `remove` and `splice` operations on the observableArray, operate on the contents, then tell the array it has been updated.

```
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var item = ko.dataFor(ui.item[0]);
            var newIndex = ui.item.index();
            var oldIndex = list.indexOf(item);

            if (oldIndex != newIndex) {
                list().splice(oldIndex, 1);
                list().splice(newIndex, 0, item);
                list.valueHasMutated();
            }
        }
```

In the example below, I have added a second list which is non-sortable, so you can see that the observableArray does reflect changes appropriately. I also added a button to create more items, and that seems to work as expected.

Important note: in testing, I have had a couple of times where the two arrays got out of sync. If you move Two above One, then One to the last position, the jQuery list gets scrambled. So this isn't a perfect fix, but it does identify the issue you're seeing (and it's probably still an issue with the observableArray and jQuery vying for control). If I rearrange the jQuery list until it matches the other list, then they get in sync again.

**Update** If you reset the contents of the observableArray, it seems to stop getting confused. This is not a great solution if your list is very long, as the redrawing will be noticeable, but it does seem to be robust. I've substituted it into the snippet.

```
    if (oldIndex != newIndex) {
      var c = list();
      list([]);
      c.splice(oldIndex, 1);
      c.splice(newIndex, 0, item);
      list(c);
    }
```

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.uiSortableList = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccesor, context) {
    var list = valueAccessor();

    $(element).sortable({
      axis: 'y',
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var item = ko.dataFor(ui.item[0]);
        var newIndex = ui.item.index();
        var oldIndex = list.indexOf(item);

        if (oldIndex != newIndex) {
          var c = list();
          list([]);
          c.splice(oldIndex, 1);
          c.splice(newIndex, 0, item);
          list(c);
        }
      }
    });
  }
};

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.headers = ko.observableArray([{
    title: 'One'
  }, {
    title: 'Two'
  }, {
    title: 'Three'
  }, {
    title: 'Four'
  }]);
  self.addItem = function() {
    self.headers.push({
      title: 'Item' + self.headers().length
    });
  };
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
console.clear();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
}
li {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: .2em;
  background-color: #777;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: headers, uiSortableList: headers" class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul data-bind="foreach: headers">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item
</button>
```

Comment: This seems to be working really fine. My list won't be that long (at least not in a hundred years or so) so the redrawing is not a problem. Thanks alot!